# Search tokens from file and replace in another ant

Tags: ant

I have one toke file " xpressionProperty.txt" which is having key value pairs as below.

```
MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER=QM_XPN
MQ_HOSTNAME=10.12.49.17
MQ_PORT=5551
MQ_CHANNEL=CHNL.XPN
MQ_USERID=mqm
MQ_PASSWORD=abc
INPUT_QUEUE1=PREPROCESSOR.QP1
INPUT_QUEUE2=PREPROCESSOR.QP2
ERROR_QUEUE=ERROR.QP1
```

and my property file is " Queue.properties " which is having below values.

```
MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER=${MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER}
MQ_HOSTNAME=${MQ_HOSTNAME}
MQ_PORT=${MQ_PORT}
MQ_CHANNEL=${MQ_PORT}
MQ_USERID=${MQ_USERID}
MQ_PASSWORD=${MQ_PASSWORD}
INPUT_QUEUE1=${INPUT_QUEUE1}
INPUT_QUEUE2=${INPUT_QUEUE2}
ERROR_QUEUE=${ERROR_QUEUE}
```

when i run ant command Queue.properties file should be updated with actual values which is in xpressionProperty.txt file. Please help me solving this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [filtersets and filters](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html).

Copy your `Queue.properties` file elsewhere like this:

```
<copy file=${queue.properties.file}
   todir="${target.dir}">
   <filterset begintoken="${"
       endtoken="}"
       filterfile="${xpression.property.file}"/>
</copy>
```

That will replace the parameters found in Queue.properties with the values in "xpressionProperty.txt".

By the way, I'd replace the `${foo}` syntax with just `@foo@` in your `Queue.properties` file. Then you don't have to specify the `begintoken` and `endtoken` parameters. Plus, that's what people expect to see as replacement values.

**WARNING: DO NOT DO THIS AS AN IN PLACE REPLACEMENT**. There is a `<replace>` task that is very similar to this, but would modify the `Queue.properties` directly. That means your `Queue.properties` file will lose its replacement values, and if someone commits the changes, you will lose them when you need to do this again.